# The y coordinate from ActionEvent send to DragOverListener is *decreasing* even when only dragging downwards

Tags: codenameone

If you try to execute the small code sample below, you can see that the dragOverListener on a given dragged label gets called with a *previous* value of y every second time.

I'm guessing it is due to the code in Component: `private void pointerDragged(final int x, final int y, final Object currentPointerPress)` which creates a `run()` which calls `pointerDragged` and is executed twice (probably interleaving with the following x,y coordinates).

This seems to be an undesired side-effect, and it creates a problem for my code since I use the difference between consecutive y values to determine if the dragged element is being dragged up or down.

Alternatively, if you have a suggestion for another reliable way for a dragged element to determine its drag direction would also be great.

````
//try to drag any element in the list downwards. Notice that every second y value will refer to the previous (smaller) value of y
Form hi1 = new Form();
hi1.setLayout(BoxLayout.y());
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    Label l = new Label("Label " + i);
    l.setDraggable(true);
    l.setDropTarget(true);
    l.addDragOverListener((e) -> {
        Log.p(l.getText()+", y=" + e.getY());
    });
    hi1.add(l);
}
hi1.show();
```
````

Comment: Why not just use scrolling? If you can try to explain what you're trying to accomplish in a high level view that would help. These specific lines are a fix for issue 1470 https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1470 which might no longer be applicable. It might make sense to remove that hack.

Comment: Not sure I understand how to get the drag direction via scrolling? My use case is that I’ve implemented my own support for drag and drop (where I insert a white space empty label below the dragged component to visually indicate the drop position) and as part of that I need the drag direction. Eg when dragging upwards, the white space must be inserted *before* the position of the component below the dragged element, and when dragging downwards, it’s the inverse. I agree the code in Component looks like a hack ;-), so if it can be removed now that might be a good solution.

Comment: If you remove the code locally does it solve the problem? If so please file an issue  (or better yet submit a pull request) and reference this conversation and we'll remove it from the trunk.

Comment: Thanks! I simply disabled the code starting with `if (dragCallbacks < 2)` and it it fixes the issue. I prefer to let you guys fix it since I prefer not to push a fix I don't understand :-) Issue created here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2951